# what will other nodes exactly do in relaying transaction process?

Tags: nodes

this question confused me long time. 
What will other nodes exactly do in relaying transaction process? I read some questions/answers, I know they will follow ethereum protocol, but what would this protocols do? for example it invoke a contract function in a transaction and change the contract state, does other nodes need run the contract and compare with anything got from the transaction ? 
In bitcoin, I know other nodes will check the transaction inputs and output and so on. And If they got new block, they also will do similiar sanity check. But I don't know in ethereum, bcz it adds contract. 
Or please could anyone point me where I can find answers in the source code.
Thank you.

Comment: Please check if the linked question above answers your question, maybe I got it wrong. If not, you can edit your question and request a reopening.

Comment: yes, it answers my question

Comment: Related http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7823/do-nodes-by-default-relay-transactions-that-fail-and-spend-all-gas-e-g-solidit